# Lotus Notes Access Logs - Where are the Logs found in Domino?

Tags: security, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

Where are the logs found in Domino?  In particular, I am looking for access (login access times and IP address) logs for Lotus Notes web mail.  Is it possible to view who logged in to a user's mailbox and when it was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logs.nsf probably, been a long time since I've used domino's!

Answer (score 0):

You can use /notes/data/domino/logs for server access logs.  THe default config would look something like access-log08082014.log, and there'd be one for each day.